# SSL on KeystoneJS with letsencrypt and apache2

Tags: node.js, express, apache2, lets-encrypt, keystonejs

I am deploying keystonejs app on Ubuntu 16 with docker-compose and having a valid letsencrypt certificate.

I have added the following settings in keystone.js

```
'ssl': true
'port': 3000,
    'admin path': 'admin',
    'ssl cert': '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem',
    'ssl key': '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem',
    'letsencrypt': (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') && {
        email: 'user@gmail.com',
        domains: ['www.mydomain.com', 'mydomain.com'],
        register: true,
        tos: true,
    },
```

Server starts fine showing me this:

```
app |
app | ------------------------------------------------
app | KeystoneJS v4.0.0 started:
app | mydomain is ready on http://0.0.0.0:3000
app | SSL Server is ready on https://0.0.0.0:3001
app | ------------------------------------------------
app |
```

But when I visit my website. it does not show it as secured from the url tab in the browser. It shows a little exclamation mark (!) Saying: your connection to this site is not secured.

I have apache2 on my server.

under /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
  ServerName  mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and under /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.le.ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
  ServerName  mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost On

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have tried pointing the ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse to 3001 port. But the site will never be accessible.
Any help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SSL in keystone. You dont need it when proxying traffic via Apache server. It will handle the certificate, and communicate with keystone locally, without SSL. Then you can block 3000 port from beeing accessible from outside.